# Can not find `pthread_setaffinity_np'?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, multicore

I used -pthread for gcc compiler, but still can not find this API. any suggestion?

Comment: Which system are you using? I find that `pthread_setaffinity_np` is not available under Cygwin.

Answer (score 5):

It's a non-standard GNU extension, as the manual and the suffix `_np` will tell you, so include the header like this:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <pthread.h>
```

Comment: Could you be more descriptive than "it does not work"? Make your entire question a bit more informative, say what you've done and say what your problem is.

Comment: compiler says _GNU_SOURCE is already defined and still ： Thread.cpp:34: error: `pthread_attr_setaffinity_np' was not declared in this scope
Thread.cpp:34: warning: unused variable 'pthread_attr_setaffinity_np'

Comment: Can you post your actual code (minimal example)? You must have an error somewhere else, it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your command must looks like this way...

$ > gcc -lpthread YourProg.c

if it is .cpp

then >>

$ > g++ -lpthread YourProg.cpp

Answer (score 0):

because it is not a posix function,so maybe you can use it in somewhere,and you can not use it in some other where.
So carefully use it.