# Android NDK and pthread

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-ndk, pthreads

I'm compiling Qt/C++ project with android NDK standalone toolchain. I’ve created standalone toolchain with make-standalone-toolchain.sh --arch=arm --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.9 --platform=android-21 command. NDK version is android-ndk-r10e. Target project uses some functions from pthread library. At compile time, I get the following error:

```
error: 'pthread_getaffinity_np' was not declared in this scope
const int err = pthread_getaffinity_np(_pthreadId, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuSetMask);
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

I've checked the header of pthread included in ndk toolchain and I did not find the declaration of pthread_getaffinity_np function.

Is pthread functionality for Android limited? How to use pthread with Android NDK properly?

Comment: As pointed out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7269859/1688185) as well as in the [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_setaffinity_np): *These functions are nonstandard GNU extensions; hence the suffix "_np" (nonportable) in the names*. Bionic has apparently no support for it (see also the NDK documentation that contains a *Bionic C Library Overview* with precisions regarding the pthread implementation and limitation).

Comment: It is true what @deltheil said. My solution is that I do not use pthread functionality. I reached this with conditional compiling, because on Android system I anyway do not use threading functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Is pthread functionality for Android limited?`

AFAIK, Yes.

<s>http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/#pthreads</s>
https://web.archive.org/web/20180602101341/http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/#pthreads

```
POSIX threads (pthreads)
The android libc, bionic, provides built-in support for pthreads, so no
additional linking (-lpthreads) is necessary. It does not implement full
POSIX threads functionality and leaves out support for read/write locks,
pthread_cancel(), process-shared mutexes and condition variables as well as
other more advanced features. Read the bionic OVERVIEW.txt for more
information.

TLS, thread-local storage, is limited to 59 pthread_key_t slots available
to applications, lower than the posix minimum of 128.
```

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: Link is dead. I'm also facing a similar problem. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/docs/status.md for our official docs about what is in which Android version.

you can also look at the `<pthread.h>` header in the NDK (current version [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/libc/include/pthread.h)) and see for example entries like:

```
pid_t pthread_gettid_np(pthread_t __pthread) __INTRODUCED_IN(21);
```

this shows that we do have the non-POSIX/non-portable (`_np`) function `pthread_gettid_np`, but that it was introduced in API level 21, so if your code needs to run on older releases you can't use it.

basically the headers are the canonical source of truth for "which functions are available in which API levels?".

for the specific case of `pthread_getaffinity_np`, no, we don't support that. you can combine `pthread_gettid_np` from `<pthread.h>` and `sched_getaffinity` from `<sched.h>` though.

Comment: I have found this question in various places. This is probably the best answer I have seen!! Thanks!
Here is how I used it with C++ threads:

cpu_set_t cpuset;

            CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
            CPU_SET(cpu_index, &cpuset);
            auto tid = pthread_gettid_np(worker_threads_.native_handle());
            int rc = sched_setaffinity(tid, sizeof(cpu_set_t),
                                        &cpuset);

Answer (score 0):

POSIX threads (pthreads) seems to be not provided for **-host** build modules.
at least here is the error for the libcrypto-host module build:

```
out/host/linux-x86/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libcrypto-host_intermediates/src/crypto/thread_pthread.o: 
In function `thread_local_init':
/media/compilation/projects/android/beagle2/external/boringssl/src/crypto/thread_pthread.c:112: 
undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
```

and the only way to fix it so far is to add -lpthread inside 
*external/boringssl/Android.mk* before directive:

```
include $(BUILD_HOST_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

example:

```
# Host shared library
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE := libcrypto-host
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDE_DIRS := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_MULTILIB := both
LOCAL_ADDITIONAL_DEPENDENCIES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/Android.mk $(LOCAL_PATH)/crypto-sources.mk
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fvisibility=hidden -DBORINGSSL_SHARED_LIBRARY -DBORINGSSL_IMPLEMENTATION -Wno-unused-parameter
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DOPENSSL_NO_ASM
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lpthread
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/crypto-sources.mk
include $(BUILD_HOST_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```